# This input is incomplete

Tags: warning-messages, conditional

I'm sorry if this is a totally simple question, but I'm new to Mathematica, and I've just spent 30mins looking through the documentation, but I can't seem to figure out why this code won't work:

```
Quadratic[n_, a_ , b_] := (n^2 + a * n + b) \;  And[Abs[b] < 1000, Abs[a]< 1000]
```

All it says is that the input is incomplete and it needs more input.

- Thanks for helping!

Comment: You probably meant `/;` instead of `\'`?

Answer (score 2):

you misspelled [Condition](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html)

Your definition should read

```
Quadratic[n_, a_, b_] := (n^2 + a*n + b) /; 
 And[Abs[b] < 1000, Abs[a] < 1000]
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the prompt answer! That's a pretty funny mistake. (: